# How to use "for" along with string replace?

Tags: javascript, str-replace

I want to make several replacements in the same string. I have this:

```js
ignoredids = [{"ignoredid":"3329"},{"ignoredid":"25895"}];
userlist = `<div id="u343">something</div><div id="u3143">something</div><div id="u25895">something</div><div id="u5343">something</div><div id="u3329">something</div>`;
```

after the replacements it should look like this:

```html
<div id="u343">something</div><div id="u3143">something</div><div id="u25895">ignore this</div><div id="u5343">something</div><div id="u3329">ignore this</div>
```

So I tried:

```
for (let { ignoredid } of ignoredids) {
  mylist = userlist.replace(`<div id="u${ignoredid}">something</div>`,`<div id="u${ignoredid}">ignore this</div>`);        
}
```

but it doesnt seem to do anything. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are expecting the code to do?  Where do you ever use `mylist`?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You had a typo `}]";` I removed the last `"` to fix. I presume it was only due to the demo sample but not in the real code ;)

Comment: mylist is only a string that will display html code in a given place. Like this `mydiv.innerHTMLl = mylist;`

Comment: Here its working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/bf0m7p5r/ so I dont get it...

Comment: @snksaint find the mistake in your fiddle :) `isMyResult === whatOPWants` :D Also, that example uses garbage hardcoded strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it now, it will only replace on the last id and assign it to the `mylist` variable, because `.replace` does not mutate the string.

If we assign to `userlist` instead of `mylist` it will work the way you want it to work, because then we're actually modifying the string on every iteration:

```js
ignoredids = [{"ignoredid": "3329"}, {"ignoredid": "25895"}];
userlist = `<div id="u343">something</div><div id="u3143">something</div><div id="u25895">something</div><div id="u5343">something</div><div id="u3329">something</div>`;

for (let { ignoredid} of ignoredids) {
  userlist = userlist.replace(`<div id="u${ignoredid}">something</div>`, `<div id="u${ignoredid}">ignore this</div>`);
}

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = userlist;
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create an Array of "u" prefixed IDs only
- Don't use `replace()` with hardcoded stuff.
- And since Regular Expression should never be used on HTML-alike strings  -  **use instead a proper DOM parser or inmemory Element**. Read about [DOMParser.parseFromString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)

```js
// Helper function
const arrHas = (arr, val) => arr.some(a => val === a);

// Your stuff:
const replacer = "IGNORE THIS";
const ignoredids = [
  {"ignoredid":"3329"},
  {"ignoredid":"25895"},
];
const userlist = `<div id="u343">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="u3143">Dolor sit amet</div>
<div id="u25895">consectetur adipisicing</div>
<div id="u5343">Elit enim </div>
<div id="u3329">Nemo eveniet</div>`;

// Create an Array of "u" prefixed IDs 
const uIDs = ignoredids.map(o => `u${o.ignoredid}`); 

// Use DOMParser!!
const DOC = new DOMParser().parseFromString(userlist, "text/html");

[...DOC.body.children].forEach(EL => {
  if (arrHas(uIDs, EL.id)) EL.textContent = replacer;
});

const result = DOC.body.innerHTML;
console.log(result)
```

`result` is now this HTML-alike String:

```sh
<div id="u343">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="u3143">Dolor sit amet</div>
<div id="u25895">IGNORE THIS</div>
<div id="u5343">Elit enim </div>
<div id="u3329">IGNORE THIS</div>
```

Comment: is this the most direct approach?

Comment: Yes. And the best one.

Comment: Alternatively you can also use document.createElement("div") instead of DOC.body.